# Hive UDTF returning ArrayList Column

Tags: java, hadoop, arraylist, hive

I am new to Hive UDTF. I have a requirement where I have to pass string values as Paratmeter in UDTF and the returning Column should be a ArrayList.

I have written the following Code:

```
public StructObjectInspector initialize(ObjectInspector[] arg0)
        throws UDFArgumentException {
        ArrayList<String> fieldNames = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<ObjectInspector> fieldOIs = new ArrayList<ObjectInspector>();
        fieldNames.add("col1");
        stringOI = (PrimitiveObjectInspector) arg0[0];
       listOi=(ListObjectInspector) arg0[0];
        fieldOIs.add(listOi.getListElementObjectInspector());
        return ObjectInspectorFactory.getStandardStructObjectInspector(fieldNames, fieldOIs);
}

@Override
public void process(Object[] record) throws HiveException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     String document = (String) stringOI.getPrimitiveJavaObject(record[0]);
     if (document == null) {
          return;
        }
    firstColumn=(String) stringOI.getPrimitiveJavaObject(record[0]);
    secondColumn=(String) stringOI.getPrimitiveJavaObject(record[1]);
    if(outputMapper.containsKey(firstColumn))
    {

        ArrayList<String> tempList=new ArrayList<String>();
        tempList=outputMapper.get(firstColumn);
        tempList.add(secondColumn);
        outputMapper.put(firstColumn,tempList);
    }
    else
    {
            childVendorList=new ArrayList<String>();
            childVendorList.add(secondColumn);
            outputMapper.put(firstColumn,childVendorList);
    }
    forward(outputMapper.get(firstColumn));

}
```

}

And I am getting the following Exception:

java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.objectinspector.primitive.LazyStringObjectInspector cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.ListObjectInspector

Can Anyone Help???

Answer (score 2):

```
listOi=(ListObjectInspector) arg0[0];
fieldOIs.add(listOi.getListElementObjectInspector());
return ObjectInspectorFactory.getStandardStructObjectInspector(fieldNames, fieldOIs);
```

This arg0[0] is a primitive object inspector. With listOi.getListElementObjectInspector(), just get a similar PrimitiveObjectInspector(like String,Integer is not a List). It should

```
fieldOIs.add(ObjectInspectorFactory.getStandardListObjectInspector(stringOI ))
```

This will specific the output column with List of type of stringOI.

Comment: Ok, in the same meaning, could you click useful button for me as award.:)